# ANGULAR: Turn off inputs in a loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a loop (ng-repeat) that generates several inputs and another loop that generates other inputs. My question is: I need to enable or disable the inputs of the second loop in function if the inputs of the first loop have data or not. Here is my code:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="rec in recursos">
    <label>{{rec.title}}</label>
    <input type="text" name="rec" ng-model="rec.desc" ng-required="true">
    <div ng-messages="myForm2.rec.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">Campo obligatorio</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="prep_par in presupuestoPartidas">
    <label>{{prep_par.title}}</label>
    <input type="number" name="prep_par" ng-model="prep_par.importe" min="0" ng-required="true" >
    <div ng-messages="myForm2.prep_par.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">Campo obligatorio</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: You can simply get the index of the input from your first loop and then disable the second input if the value corresponding the indexed element is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first loop uses the array `$scope.firstLoop`, you just need to set the `ng-disabled` of the inputs of the second loop to the `$scope.firstLoop.length` variable. If the array is empty, then the inputs of the second loop are disabled.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="rec in recursos">
<label>{{rec.title}}</label>
<input type="text" name="rec" ng-model="rec.desc" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="firstLoop.length">
<div ng-messages="myForm2.rec.$error">
  <div ng-message="required">Campo obligatorio</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I have not explained well. My condition is that the user adds data,  value!=''...